How to completely reset Spotlight search data on macos 15 beta?
My Spotlight is stupidly broken, because it is searching for a non-existent contact.
Rebuilding the index does not help at all, of course, I really need to erase all Spotlight data.

Please explain what you have done to "rebuild" the index. I know when I think "rebuild" that includes erasing the existing index.

I used this guide https://support.apple.com/en-us/102321

How do you know that Spotlight is searching for a Contact that doesn't exist? Also: you're using beta software, which may well contain problems that Apple needs to fix. Make sure you report the problem to Apple using the Feedback Assistant.

oh no, i do not think that i have problem of the beta version. i am still getting a contact, that was removed almost a year ago in search results

I had similar issue with Spotlight in the beta (and final/release) version of macOS 15 Sequoia.
I used the following commands to clear out all the spotlight files and it is working now.
sudo mdutil -X /
sudo mdutil -X /System/Volumes/Data
sudo mdutil -X /System/Volumes/Preboot
sudo mdutil -X /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/
sudo mdutil -X /Volumes/<To each of the mounted volumes you have>

